# What happens when I `Object.assign` to a primitive type in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I discovered that you can call `Object.assign` on a `string` or `number` type in javascript to get a sort of 'enhanced' primitive type.

```
// closure used to create object for simplicity
function makeObj() {

    let value = 6;

    let enhancedValue = Object.assign(value, {
        set: () => 'from the set method'
    })

    return {
        someValue: enhancedValue
    };
}

let myObj = makeObj();

// output is from nodejs

console.log(myObj.someValue); // accessing
// outputs: `{ [Number: 6] set: [Function: set] }`
console.log(myObj.someValue + 3); // using
// outputs: `9`
console.log(myObj.someValue.set()) // using method
// outputs: `from the set method`
```

So my question is: what type is this now? Is there any spec defining this behavior? Is there any reason not to do this? Could you explain what's going on here?

Comment: All the primitive types can be "boxed" into objects. There's a `Number` prototype, `String` prototype, etc.

Comment: Basically a `new Number(6)` object with your extra properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, almost all primitive types have an equivalent object type. So while `"x"` is a string primitive, `new String("x")` is a String object. Similarly, there are number primitives and `Number` objects, and boolean primitives and `Boolean` objects, etc.

The first step of [`Object.assign`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.assign) is to take the first argument and use the [abstract ToObject operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toobject) on it, which performs that primitive-to-object step. From that point forward, it uses the object returned by ToObject. (ToObject just returns its argument if it's already an object.)

That object is what `assign` ultimately returns.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thank you for the answer, it explains a lot! My last question is: is there any reason not to add methods to strings/numbers/etc? Is this bad practice?

Comment: @Bergi: Gah, my head was elsewhere and thinking in ES5 for some reason. I was going to go back and explain the difference, but it was tangential anyway, so I just removed it.

Comment: @RicoKahler: You'll find two schools of thought on that, both with faithful, vocal, reasonable adherents: "Nope! No reason, go for it, that's the point of primitives after all. Beware naming conflicts." and "Yes, there are; You'll inevitably conflict with someone else doing the same thing. And even if you don't conflict with another script doing an extension, you may well end up with a naming conflict with future standards." Both camps can agree on at least one thing: Never, ever, add *enumerable* properties to built-in prototypes. :-)

Comment: @RicoKahler: There's also the question of how the code you do it in is going to be used. A library that extends built-in language prototypes (the venerable PrototypeJS, for instance) is, in today's world, likely to get criticism levelled at it. But if your code is only for use in your app and you're sensible about names and have a good testing regime in place to catch future issues early as the standard library evolves, that's a different proposition.

Comment: @TJCrowder, does that mean I should actually 'box' the primitive then use `Object.defineProperty` on the boxed primitive instead of `Object.assign`? `Object.assign` copies enumerable properties only right?

Comment: @RicoKahler: Yes. If you do it, I suggest using `Object.defineProperty` (for just one) or `Object.defineProperties` (for several). The default for the `enumerable` flag (like all flags in a property descriptor) is `false`.

Comment: @RicoKahler No, T.J. Crowder was talking only about the native prototypes (like `Number.prototype`) that all primitives. If you are going to create your own object instances, you can do with them whatever you want (including enumerable properties). Though boxed primitives are just weird and it is generally recommended not to use them at all - rather create a proper class that represents what you need.