# ObjectAssign transforms bool to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use Redux and I have problems with reducers.

*isLoading: true* - it's what I send in action.

*isLoading: {}* - it's what I get in props after reducer.

How to fix it?

I use it:

```
export function movieDiscoverIsLoading(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MOVIES_DISCOVER_LOADING:
            return Object.assign({}, state, action.isLoading);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function movieDiscoverItems(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MOVIES_DISCOVER_RESULTS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, action.items);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Logs:

[image: Logs]

And additional question:
how can I change a few fields in copied object using Object.assign or spread operator?

When I tried something like that:
`{ ...state, ...{items: action.items, isLoading: false}}` 
I've got nested object, where isLoading is inside of items.

Comment: Here's why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560540/what-happens-when-i-object-assign-to-a-primitive-type-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mutate the initial state passed to reducer. Seems like you should return `boolean` instead of `object`

```
export function movieDiscoverIsLoading(state = false, action) {
    // it is already boolean           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    switch (action.type) {
        case MOVIES_DISCOVER_LOADING:
            // why do you return an object here instead of boolean
            return Object.assign({}, state, action.isLoading);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

To fix it just replace:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, action.isLoading);
```

to

```
return action.isLoading;
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to assign a boolean here:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, action.isLoading);
```

I guess you want to assign an object witj an `isLoading` proerty instead:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { isLoading: action.isLoading });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Lodasd instead, _.merge you will have the desired behavior.